# Set a cookie on a text link click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I want to create a cookie when someone clicks a text link. The idea is that they will only see the link if they haven't clicked it before, once they click it, the cookie is created. I check if the cookie exists, if it does, do not show the link.

Here is my **Controller** to create the cookie:

```
public class SurveySurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController

{
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("ClickedSurvey")]
    public ActionResult ClickedSurvey()
    {
        // Create a cookie if the link is clicked.
        HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("surveyCookie");
        Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

        return CurrentUmbracoPage();
    }
}
```

How can I call this `ActionResult` when someone clicks a text link from my PartialView?

Here is the link in the **View:**

```
<a href="https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/XW9FHF7" target="_blank">Some Survey</a>
```

All I want is to call the `ActionResult` when someone clicks the link.

Is there a good way to do this without using JavaScript?

Comment: What is the intention of this cookie?

Comment: If someone clicks the link, I create the cookie  to use like a flag to hide the link so they only see the survey once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
@Html.ActionLink("Some Survey","ClickedSurvey","SurveySurfaceController")
```

instead of your `<a>` linking
to surveymonkey, your action should redirect to the link - use `Response.Redirect(somePage);`

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to reload your page you have to use `AJAX` to this action, Other wise create an `action link` to this very particular Action

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text,"ClickedSurvey","SurveySurface") //generates an achor tag
```

Also you would be neding *current HTTP Context* for setting up the cookie in MVC as

```
 System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(yourcookie)
```

Also for redirecting use

```
return Redirect("your Url")
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see three viable solutions:

1. Use JavaScript to issue an ajax request to the action you've defined;
2. Use JavaScript to set the cookie client-side;
3. Instead of opening the link directly, open your action first and then issue a `Response.Redirect()`.

Personally, I would use the first approach.

As a side note, better use `Response.SetCookie()`, because `Response.Cookie.Add()` can cause multiple cookies to be added, whereas `SetCookie` will update an existing cookie if it exists.